# how to get data from nested json which is not having name in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, cordova, gson

i have a JSON like below.
this is sample json.. i have my json structure like this. if this json has any error please ignore that.

```
[
[
"{"category_id":1,"category_name":"1Appetizers","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":13,"category_name":"Buffet","image_id":0}"
],

[
"{"subcategory_id":1,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Beer","image_id":0}",
"{"subcategory_id":2,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Wine","image_id":0}"
],
[
"{"menucategory_id":1,"menucategory_id":12,"menucategory_name":"dosa","image_id":0}",
"{"menucategory_id":2,"menucategory_id":12,"menucategory_name":"idly","image_id":0}"
]
]
```

how do i parse this JSON in android. i want to show category_name in one page and other details in some other page. there is no name for object.

Comment: First of all this is not correct json format. `category_id":1,"` in this `,` has to be after `"`, like `category_id":1",`

Comment: Looks like you're looking for JSONArray

Comment: @Aniruddha you saved me I was about to start parsing it

Comment: It's terrible format, I dont think you can deserialize it automatically without writing own deserializer. I'd suggest you to change it.

Comment: @IllegalArgument You're welcome. That is the first thing I do when I see json :D. @user please check the format in `jsonlint.com`

Answer (score 1):

Like the other commenters have mentioned this is not real JSON.
But here is an attempt to answer your question anyway.

I would create objects that represents the data you want to serialize and deserialize to and form JSON.  It looks like you would have objects Category, Subcategory, and MenuCategory. Then you would probably have another object that holds lists of those three objects.

Then I would use GSON to serialize and deserialize your object. Let it do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code. it might help you

```
    // say you have your json in a String named jsonString
    try
    {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        JSONArray firstJsonArray = array.getJSONArray(0);
        JSONArray secondJsonArray = array.getJSONArray(1);
        JSONArray thirdJsonArray = array.getJSONArray(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            JSONObject firstJsonObject = firstJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject secondJsonObject = secondJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject thirdJsonObject = thirdJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String categoryName = firstJsonObject.getString("category_name");
            String subcategoryName = secondJsonObject.getString("subcategory_name");
            String menucategoryName = thirdJsonObject.getString("menucategory_name");

            // Now here you can use these values to do anything
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"category_id":1,Category_name":"1Appetizers",,"image_id":0} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject